# Error al utilizar highcharts en laravel?

Tags: laravel

actualmente estoy utilizando la librería higcharts en laravel, pero al utilizar la siguiente consulta.
Pero al utilizar dicha consulta se genera el siguiente error:
Undefined function: 7 ERROR: no existe la función month(timestamp without time zone)
La cual no logro solucionar, soy nuevo en laravel, si alguien podria guiarme que tenga mas experiencia, mi base de datos esta en postgresql.

```
$positivos = Paciente::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("Month(created_at)"))
                    ->pluck('count');
```

Comment: Has intentado con `DB::raw("date_part('month', created_at))`, creo que no funciona `month` en postgresql

Comment: Gracias por responder, si justamente es lo primero que intente al buscarlo en internet, pero es el mismo error:  Undefined function: 7 ERROR: no existe la función date_part(timestamp without time zone)

Comment: @RafaelEscobar la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) indica usar un `EXTRACT` ¿ya probaste con eso?

Comment: Actualmente lo estoy usando de esta menarea: $positivos = Paciente::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
                    ->where('pacientes.resultado','Positivo')
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("created_at"))
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("extract(MONTH from created_at)", "=", Carbon::now()->month))
                    ->pluck('count');

Comment: @RafaelEscobar entonces dicha función te sirvió o no?

Comment: no, lo que quiero conseguir es la cantidad de registros que se carguen de manera diaria, y que en mis graficos los visualice, pero solo me enlista a cantidad de registros que tengo guardado, disculpe no conozo bien las reglas para publicar en stack overflow.

Comment: @RafaelEscobar ahi el error entonces ya es otro, ahora deberías publicar la solución para la pregunta original aqui que era el problema de la función de postgresql, posterior abrir una nueva pregunta donde formules el como hacer tu query para obtener el resultado que deseas

Comment: Entiendo, gracias..